# DataTables Column Filter Add-on displaying, but output is not filtered

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

i have just added DataTables Column Filter Add-on to my datatable, it shows the columns search fields on the footer. But if i type in the the "Processing" is done for a short time but the results is not updated. i.e filtered.

I am using codeIgniters ignitedDatatables in the backend. Everything else works fine (pagination,global search on top right,)
I found no clue on the net whether i need to configure something else in order for the filter to work.

Here is my view-

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/eshop/css/admin/style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/eshop/css/admin/smoothness/jquery-ui-custom.css"/>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {   
            $('#data_table').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,           
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url() ?>grid/getCustomers"
            } ).columnFilter(
            {
                aoColumns: [
                    {
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    {
                        type: "text",
                        bRegex: true,
                        bSmart: true
                    },
                    null
                ]
            }
        );

        } );

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="widget_body">
        <table id="data_table" class="data_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot style="background-color: whitesmoke;">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

My control

```
//display
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('datatableview');
}

//ajax request handler
public function getCustomers()
{
    $this->load->library('datatables');

    $this->datatables->select('id,first_name,last_name')
            ->from('data_table');
    echo $this->datatables->generate();


}
```

As I said earlier 2 input boxes appear at the bottom of ID and first name but i cant see change of display once i type into the boxes

If i type = "Bjo" in the 2nd column's input box the get request from firebug i found is

```
_=1354249241305
bRegex=false
bRegex_0=false
bRegex_1=true
bRegex_2=false
bSearchable_0=true
bSearchable_1=true
bSearchable_2=true
bSortable_0=true
bSortable_1=true
bSortable_2=true
iColumns=3
iDisplayLength=10
iDisplayStart=0
iSortCol_0=0
iSortingCols=1
mDataProp_0=0
mDataProp_1=1
mDataProp_2=2
sColumns=
sEcho=22
sRangeSeparator=~
sSearch=
sSearch_0=
sSearch_1=Bjo
sSearch_2=
sSortDir_0=asc
```

The response is found

```
{"sEcho":22,"iTotalRecords":30,"iTotalDisplayRecords":30,"aaData":[["1","Shabab","Haider"],["2","Anas","Numan"],["3","Bjoy","Manik"],["4","Bjoy","Manik"],["5","Bjoy","Manik"],["6","Bjoy","Manik"],["7","Bjoy","Manik"],["8","Bjoy","Manik"],["9","Bjoy","Manik"],["10","Bjoy","Manik"]],"sColumns":"id,first_name,last_name"}
```

Edit: Its been a while since i used that add on. I created a branch with my filtering codes in github. but it needs some testing. I would test it myself when i get the time- meanwhile if someone wants to be a dear and do it for others-

```
https://github.com/shababhsiddique/Ignited-Datatables/blob/Branche_Column_Filter/application/libraries/Datatables.php
```

Here is the actual code I used long time ago. Its very old check out if it works with your version

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzKzAVzAWPRgcmNCbGhnU3pqaW8/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Did you check dev tools/firebug for the request? It's likely sending back a 500 or db error.

Comment: What information can i give you? Please tell me. I havent previously used this type of tools. Anyway i have updated the question with the get request from firebug

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: i have added the request and response from firebug for a example case in my question. please check

Comment: Check out this example: http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured there was a problem with the json generating library.

The [ignited datatables library](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/) is incomplete. I had to modify their library to

I dont remember all the changes that I made (there where quite a few) but I remember I changed all input->get to input->post and all $_GET to $_POST

I think i also modified this function

```
protected function get_filtering()
```

This is the current edited library I use-

> `{ http://162.212.134.58/shabab/Datatables.zip }`

You can match your library with mine to find out.

I havent updated to latest datatables yet.

Comment: i have same problem. can you help me solve it. or can you update your answer with the solution you have done so me and others like me might be able to solve our problem with your solution.

Comment: hello Sizzling Code, sorry for replying late. I just came to SO after a while and your comment is the first thing i am writing here in SO in a month. If you havent solved your problem already just keep in touch I will try to edit the answer.

Comment: @shababhsiddique     can you please post the modified datatable lib. i am facing same kind of  problem

Comment: Its been a while since i used that add on. I created a branch with my filtering codes in github. but it needs some testing.
https://github.com/shababhsiddique/Ignited-Datatables/blob/Branche_Column_Filter/application/libraries/Datatables.php

Here is the actual code I used long time ago. Its very old check out if it works with your version
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzKzAVzAWPRgcmNCbGhnU3pqaW8/view?usp=sharing